Server PRC , from client to server, doesn`t work for some reason
Rpc is working, but rotation on the client is lagging. I know, maybe this code is weird but I am very new to C++.
void AHalfDeadCharacter::ChangeCamera()
{
    if (IsDefaultCamera == true) {
        FollowCamera->Deactivate();
        FirstPersonCamera->Activate();
        IsDefaultCamera = false;
    }
    else {
        FollowCamera->Activate();
        FirstPersonCamera->Deactivate();
        IsDefaultCamera = true;
    }
}
void AHalfDeadCharacter::SetFirstPerson(AHalfDeadCharacter* Player1)
{
    if (Player1->IsDefaultCamera == false) {
        Player1->CharacterRotation = (FRotator(0.f, Player1->FirstPersonCamera->GetComponentRotation().Yaw, Player1->GetActorRotation().Roll));
        Player1->SetActorRotation(Player1->CharacterRotation);
        if (Player1->HasAuthority() == false) {
            Server_SetFirstPerson(Player1);
        }
    }
        
}
void AHalfDeadCharacter::Server_SetFirstPerson_Implementation(AHalfDeadCharacter* Player)
{
    Player->SetActorRotation(Player->CharacterRotation);
    Player->CharacterRotation = (FRotator(0.f, Player->FirstPersonCamera->GetComponentRotation().Yaw, Player->GetActorRotation().Roll));
    if (this->GetActorRotation() != Player->CharacterRotation) {
        this->SetActorRotation(Player->CharacterRotation);
        if (this->GetActorRotation() != Player->CharacterRotation) {
            this->SetActorRotation(Player->CharacterRotation);
        }
    }
}

bool AHalfDeadCharacter::Server_SetFirstPerson_Validate(AHalfDeadCharacter* Player)
{
    return true;
}



void AHalfDeadCharacter::GetLifetimeReplicatedProps(TArray< FLifetimeProperty >& OutLifetimeProps) const {
    Super::GetLifetimeReplicatedProps(OutLifetimeProps);

    DOREPLIFETIME(AHalfDeadCharacter, CharacterRotation);
}

void AHalfDeadCharacter::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    SetFirstPerson(this);
}

I tried different variations of replication First Person Rotation, but I don't think I should share this experience.
